# SAP GUI script sometimes randomly crashes (object not found by ID)

Tags: python, sap-gui

So, I have two SAP GUI scripts, both of them are running a simple report in SE16, exporting it to Excel and that's all. My Python script heavily relies on this data, yet, half of the time when I go back to the computer the VBS script crashed.

Nothing changes between the attempts, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, with the same data...

The GUI script itself was done with the help of the record function, after looking at the resulting code I realized that I have absolutely no desire of ever learning this language (how do you even figure out the objectID of each button, vkeys are weird, etc).

Is there a simple way to make this (and the same with EKPO) crash-proof? I guess I'd need to show which object is not found, but ever since I started to write this post, no crashes happened, it only hanged without an error message...

This is the Python part of the code, it runs the VBS script. Based on Googling, it is possible to include the VBS code directly in Python, based on the VBS below, how bothersome would it be and would it (crystal ball time) solve my random crashes?

```
def create_ausp(local_raw):
    user = os.getlogin()
    file = rf"C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\Reporting\AUSP.XLSX"
    local_raw["Vendor"].drop_duplicates().to_clipboard(index=False)
    if os.path.exists(file):
        os.remove(file)
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        os.startfile(rf"C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\Scripts\AUSP.vbs")
        while not os.path.exists(file):
            time.sleep(1)
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        ausp_headers = ["Vendor", "SAP default material group"]
        df = pd.read_excel("AUSP.xlsx")
        # df.drop(columns=["Internal char no."], inplace=True) #sometimes comes up in SAP, uncomment if value error happens
        df.columns = ausp_headers
        os.startfile(rf"C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\Reporting\AUSP close.ahk")
    return df
```

VBS script:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "se16n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtGD-TAB").text = "ausp"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtGD-TAB").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSE16NSELFIELDS_TC/btnPUSH[4,1]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSE16NSELFIELDS_TC/btnPUSH[4,1]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 24
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 8
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[18]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSE16NSELFIELDS_TC/chkGS_SELFIELDS-MARK[5,1]").selected = true
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSE16NSELFIELDS_TC/chkGS_SELFIELDS-MARK[5,7]").selected = true
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGD-MAX_LINES").text = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSE16NSELFIELDS_TC/ctxtGS_SELFIELDS-LOW[2,2]").text = "DEFAULT_MATERIAL_GROUP"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGD-MAX_LINES").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtGD-MAX_LINES").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_VARIANT"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Reporting"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "AUSP.XLSX"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 9
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 11
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3
```

Comment: `a simple report in SE16` why don't you query the DB stuff directly from Python?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar to your code.
I had a python script that first opened SAP and logged in, and then ran a VBS script to download two excel files, and then run another python script to process the data.

Only recently have I managed to merge it all into one python script. Although it's still VBS code, only embedded in python through the win32com module.
I haven't found any better way to create the SAP code than to record it in the SAP gui, just as you did. I did find it quite easy to do and merge it into python though.

Perhaps it can help you with your needs.

```
import psutil
import subprocess
import time
import win32com.client
from win32com import client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

if "saplogon.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter()):
    print("SAP is running")
else:
    print("SAP is not running. Starting...")
    subprocess.check_call(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\sapshcut.exe', '-system=PE1', '-client=500', f'-user={sapuser}', f'-pw={password}', '-language=EN'])
    time.sleep(20)

SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    exit

application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    SapGuiAuto = None
    exit

connection = application.Children(0)
if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    application = None
    SapGuiAuto = None
    exit

session = connection.Children(0)
if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    connection = None
    application = None
    SapGuiAuto = None
    exit

print("Downloading excel files from SAP")

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/ncoois"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TOPBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1100/cmbPPIO_ENTRY_SC1100-PPIO_LISTTYP").key = "PPIOO000"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/chkP_KZ_E1").selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/chkP_KZ_E2").selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/ctxtS_WERKS-LOW").text = "ika1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/ctxtP_SYST1").text = "TECO"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/ctxtP_SYST2").text = "CNF"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_SELBLOCK/tabpSEL_00/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_SELBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1200/chkP_KZ_E2").setFocus()
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(8)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell(-1,"")
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").selectAll()
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").contextMenu()
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem("&XXL")
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").setFocus()
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey(4)
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = f"C:\\users\\{user}\\Documents"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "operations.XLSX"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 15
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press()
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press()
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane(267,40,False)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TOPBLOCK:PPIO_ENTRY:1100/cmbPPIO_ENTRY_SC1100-PPIO_LISTTYP").key = "PPIOH000"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press()
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell(-1,"")
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").selectAll()
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").contextMenu()
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCUSTOM/shellcont/shell/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem("&XXL")
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = f"C:\\users\\{user}\\Documents"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "header.XLSX"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 12
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press()
```